# Obfuscating WASM File so Antivirus/Others Don't Block It

Tags: webassembly

I have a non-profit Monero pool mining website where I want to let the user specify their Monero address and mine in their browser/app. The problem is the leading Github repo uses a WASM file that's blocked by Windows. Is there a way of obfuscating/repackaging the code so it's not detected?

Answer (score 2):

Most WebAssembly examples use HTTP to fetch a wasm file then compile it. However, this is not the only way to obtain a binary wasm module - you could base64 encode it as a string, decode, then compile it.

You can find an example of this approach in the following rollup plugin:

https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-wasm

Comment: excellent answer... but wont antivirus pick up on the wasm once it's decoded?

Comment: I am unaware of any anti-virus that blocks webassembly. Do you have the details of a product that does?

Comment: it actually runs but if you try to download it Windows blocks it